Adding more data to firestore upon completion of a purchase
I'm trying to add more data to my users collection in Firebase Firestore but for whatever reason the payment method I have setup with passkit throws an exception when ran in the simulator.
Can anyone help with my issue?
Auth ViewModel:
import Foundation
import PassKit
import Firebase

typealias PaymentCompletionHandler = (Bool) -> Void

class PaymentHandler: NSObject {
    var paymentController: PKPaymentAuthorizationController?
    var paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem]()
    var paymentStatus = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure
    var completionHandler: PaymentCompletionHandler?
    @Published public var orderNumber = UUID()
    @Published public var createEvent = AuthViewModel().createEvent()
    
    static let supportedNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [.visa, .masterCard]
    
    func startPayment(products: [Products], total: Int, completion: @escaping PaymentCompletionHandler) {
        completionHandler = completion
        
        paymentSummaryItems = []
        
        products.forEach {
            product in
            let item =  PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: product.name, amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(product.price).00"), type: .final)
            paymentSummaryItems.append(item)
        }
        
        let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(total).00"), type: .final)
        paymentSummaryItems.append(total)
        
        let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.mikey.newbold.ToftwoodSocialClubApp"
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .threeDSecure
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "GB"
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "GBP"
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = PaymentHandler.supportedNetworks
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = [.name]
        
        paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        paymentController?.delegate = self
        paymentController?.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in
            if presented {
                debugPrint("Presented payment controller")
                
            } else {
                debugPrint("Failed to present controller")
            }
        })
    }
}
        
extension PaymentHandler: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
        let errors = [Error]()
        let status = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success
        
        self.paymentStatus = status
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult(status: status, errors: errors))
    }
    
    
    
    func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
        controller.dismiss {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.paymentStatus == .success {
                    if let completionHandler = self.completionHandler{
                        completionHandler(true)
                        
                    }
                    do {
                        self.createEvent
                    }
                }
                
                else {
                    if let completionHandler = self.completionHandler {
                        completionHandler(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Cart Manager:
import Foundation
import PassKit

class CartManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var products: [Products] = []
    @Published private(set) var total: Int = 0
    
    let paymentHandler = PaymentHandler()
    @Published var paymentSuccess = false
    
    func addToCart(product: Products) {
        products.append(product)
        total += product.price
    }
    
    func removeFromCart(product: Products) {
        products = products.filter {$0.id != product.id}
        total -= product.price
    }
    
    func pay() {
        paymentHandler.startPayment(products: products, total: total) { success in
            self.paymentSuccess = success
            self.products = []
            self.total = 0
        }
    }
    
    
}

Payment Handler
import Foundation
import PassKit
import Firebase

typealias PaymentCompletionHandler = (Bool) -> Void

class PaymentHandler: NSObject {
    var paymentController: PKPaymentAuthorizationController?
    var paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem]()
    var paymentStatus = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure
    var completionHandler: PaymentCompletionHandler?
    @Published public var orderNumber = UUID()
    @Published public var createEvent = AuthViewModel().createEvent()
    
    static let supportedNetworks: [PKPaymentNetwork] = [.visa, .masterCard]
    
    func startPayment(products: [Products], total: Int, completion: @escaping PaymentCompletionHandler) {
        completionHandler = completion
        
        paymentSummaryItems = []
        
        products.forEach {
            product in
            let item =  PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: product.name, amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(product.price).00"), type: .final)
            paymentSummaryItems.append(item)
        }
        
        let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(total).00"), type: .final)
        paymentSummaryItems.append(total)
        
        let paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = paymentSummaryItems
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.mikey.newbold.ToftwoodSocialClubApp"
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .threeDSecure
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "GB"
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "GBP"
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = PaymentHandler.supportedNetworks
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingContactFields = [.name]
        
        paymentController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        paymentController?.delegate = self
        paymentController?.present(completion: { (presented: Bool) in
            if presented {
                debugPrint("Presented payment controller")
                
            } else {
                debugPrint("Failed to present controller")
            }
        })
    }
}
        
extension PaymentHandler: PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
        let errors = [Error]()
        let status = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.success
        
        self.paymentStatus = status
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult(status: status, errors: errors))
    }
    
    
    
    func paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController) {
        controller.dismiss {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.paymentStatus == .success {
                    if let completionHandler = self.completionHandler{
                        completionHandler(true)
                        
                    }
                    do {
                        self.createEvent
                    }
                }
                
                else {
                    if let completionHandler = self.completionHandler {
                        completionHandler(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've attempted to print out a uuid which works fine but when I come to actually bind a piece of data to firebase, it won't allow it

What do you mean by "passkit throws an exception when ran in the simulator"?  Please edit the question to show the error message, and do enough debugging to figure out which line of code causes it.

Also, where is your code that deals with Firestore, as you've mentioned in the title? Is that really part of the problem here?

Sorry, I've updated it as I restored my code back to a previous state

It's still not clear what the exception is or which line of code causes it.  Please edit the question to share your debugging details.

The code itself doesn't throw an exception, however when I run it in the simulator it says: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __NSConcreteUUID

That looks to me like an exception thrown somewhere in your app's code when it calls a Firebase API.  I think you should do some debugging to figure out the first line that causes it, then edit the question with your details (don't leave your details in comments).
